# php compare version.txt with current version

Tags: php, file-get-contents, remote-server

hello i find this script an am trying to get it to work but am getting. 
**update available** even when both version are the same., dont know what am doing wrong.

```
define('REMOTE_VERSION', 'http://remoteip/version.txt');
define('VERSION', '1.0.0');
$script = file_get_contents(REMOTE_VERSION);
$version = VERSION;
if($version==$script) {

    echo "<div class=success> 
    <p>You have the latest version!</p> 
    </div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class=error> 
    <p>There is a update available!</p> 
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: what do you see when you `var_dump($version, $script);`?

Comment: So what is the value of $script?

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in provided  url try to echo $script to see the result

Comment: hey Andreas the $script it a the file with '1.0.0' as the remote server version

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your REMOTE_VERSION file includes a line-break after its (theorically) unique line `1.0.0`.

Then `$script` really contains "1.0.0\n", and so can't match VERSION.